# How to create multiple columns with space in between and same heights with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a parent div or class=row and two children with class=col-xs-6 each. I want there to be space between then but also have borders. So I added a child div to each. The col-xs-6 class gives a 15px padding, so I get my space. Now the problem is that I want them to be the same size.

- I added display:table-row to the row
- I added display:table-cell and float:none to the two child columns. It gives the divs equal height.

My problem is that the second child div that contains the content is smaller than the first one. So the solid border is not drawn to equal heights. How can the child div inherit the parent size?

[image]

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
  <div style="background:yellow; padding:10px; display:table-row" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="display:table-cell; float:none; border:dashed">
      <div style="background:gray; border:solid">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div style="display:table-cell; float:none; border:dashed" class="col-xs-6">
      <div style="background:lightblue; border:solid;">
      <p class="text-center">hello world</p>
      <p class="text-center">foobar !</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Code: https://jsbin.com/babomib/edit?html,output

Basically, I want the div with blue background match the height of the parent. The parent would match the tallest div due to the table setup.

---

EDIT: as per the suggested answer, I added a fixed height to the parent div and then said height:inherit for the children. This seems to break the responsive stuff. The text bleeds through the divs.

[image]

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
  <div style="background:yellow; padding:10px; display:table-row; height:400px" class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6" style="display:table-cell; float:none; border:dashed; height:inherit">
  <div style="background:gray; border:solid; height:inherit">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>

<div style="display:table-cell; float:none; border:dashed; height: inherit" class="col-xs-6">
  <div style="background:lightblue; border:solid; height:inherit">
  <p class="text-center">hello world</p>
  <p class="text-center">foobar !</p>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the parent div to use

```
display: flex;
```

And the children to use

```
flex: 1;
```

This will give you automatically equal heights.

You can find everything about about Flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I have also created a [demo](http://codepen.io/victorbarbu/pen/MKzrrR) of this.

Comment: Hi! If you found my answer useful, please upvote and accept it! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You must explicitly set the height of your parent div container (ie: `100px`) and then on your inner elements set the height to `100%`.

You cannot just set `height: 100%` on an element if it's parent doesn't have an explicit height. If somewhere up the element tree there is a parent with an explicit height, and all the children's heights are set to `100%`, then all of those children will be the exact same height as the parent with the explicit height declaration.

---

I'm not going to get into the how it's bad-practice to inline styles like you have in your example, or about how `display: table-cell` is an anti-pattern (tables are for data, not layouts). I will link you this updated fiddle so that you can see a working example of what you want:

https://jsbin.com/gifaxo/3/edit?html,output

If there is overflow, it's because `#container` has an explicit height of like `200px`. You could set that to `100%` too and then set it's parent (the `body element I think)` to 100% as well and then all elements will take up 100% height of the page. Overflow should default to `scroll` so you won't see ugly overflow.

Comment: If I add a height, it screws up the bootstrap responsiveness when the screen shrinks as the text inside bleeds out of the parent div. I updated the code in jsbin and added a screenshot to the original question. Thanks. I am learning css.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Lunny. The inline css was for jsbin, but I see it builds bad practice. I also noticed you removed all the table stuff in your answer. I will spend some time understanding your solution. Thank you.

Comment: my site has one container. I don't know in advance how big it is going to be. So I removed the height from it and added to the row element. The child divs still work with 100%. This all works beautifully with xs class. But suppose, I replace xs with md, it breaks when the screen is too small. My parent row (highlighted yellow) is only 300px, but my second column moves below the first and outside the yellow background. How would you recommend fixing this? I added an example:https://jsbin.com/wewanu/edit?html,output.